# Logo not showing in invoice PDF

Tags: magento2, invoice-pdf

I have uploaded a logo (200x50) for invoices in the admin (Magento 2.2.5) but it is not showing in the pdf.

I have cleared the cache and reindexed but no luck.

Does anyone know why the logo is not showing?

Comment: Hi Garry, please provide more information about your issue

Comment: Fixed now. All I had done was add image as per link Serge's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

check your images path and PDF templates. Also, the format of a file is important. I need more details for help you: PDF sample, image what's uploaded and etc.

The main strategy for solving 90% Magento issues is:

1. Read Magento logs.
2. Check you mode: developer / production.
3. Clear caches & indexes.
4. Run rebuild of static content.
5. Check templates and make sure what everything is ok (pathes to images are correct and other things)

The manual are here: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-change-pdf-invoice-logo-shippment-logo-magento-2.html

Without any details answer may be too abstract.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed the instructions as per your link but no luck. I have cleared caches, re-indexed and rebuilt static content. I haven't changed any templates, just uploaded image via admin. Image is located at pub/media/sales/store/logo/stores/3/AOW_Invoice.jpg

Comment: Don't worry, got it working now. Was looking at an invoice from different site!!!